# Find positions from other list and apply that positions in other list

Tags: python, list

I have 3 lists, for example

```
list1 = [30,14,42,17,18]

list2 = [17,18,6,7,30,9,5,14,3,42,33]

list3 = [[-25,54,789,0.56],[-5,4,9,0.5],[-5,4,0.009,0.8],[-5,456,7,56],
[-5,4,9,0.6],[-2,4,9,-0.578],[-2,0.5,-7,-0.6],[-25,-50,78,0.1],[-4,-58,79,0.6],
[-2,5,7,4],[-5,54,43,0.45]]
```

The length of list2 and list3 are same.

My question is each value from `list1` is taken, find its position in `list2`, extract value from `list3` from that same position. These lists are generated during runtime i.e. IDs and values varies in runtime.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension,

```
In [67]: print [list3[j] for j in [list2.index(i) for i in list1]]
Out[67]: 
[[-5, 4, 9, 0.6],
 [-25, -50, 78, 0.1],
 [-2, 5, 7, 4],
 [-25, 54, 789, 0.56],
 [-5, 4, 9, 0.5]]
```

Or

```
In [69]: print [list3[list2.index(i)] for i in list1]
Out[69]: 
[[-5, 4, 9, 0.6],
 [-25, -50, 78, 0.1],
 [-2, 5, 7, 4],
 [-25, 54, 789, 0.56],
 [-5, 4, 9, 0.5]]
```

Comment: `[list3[list2.index(i)] for i in list1]` still has an average time complexity of *O(n^2)* because for each iteration over `list1` it needs *O(n)* to find `i` in `list2` using the `list.index` method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension with `enumerate` to create a number-to-index mapping for `dict2`, and then use the mapping to map the numbers in `list1` to the corresponding sublist in `list3` at the mapped indices:

```
mapping = {n: i for i, n in enumerate(list2)}
print([list3[mapping[n]] for n in list1])
```

This outputs:

```
[[-5, 4, 9, 0.6], [-25, -50, 78, 0.1], [-2, 5, 7, 4], [-25, 54, 789, 0.56], [-5, 4, 9, 0.5]]
```

Note that creating a mapping first reduces the average time complexity of the problem to *O(n)*.